# Puppeteer close new tab

Tags: tabs, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer and I have a little problem that once in a while new tab with ad appears, and stops the whole script. I'm looking for a way to basically detect when 3rd tab in browser window is open and close this 3rd tab (It is always the 3rd - first is blank, second is my page that i need and third is this ad).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide an example of this happening? It's sort of hard to offer a solution without seeing the problem concretely as a [mcve]. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

try {
  browser.addListener('targetcreated', async (target) => {
    if (target.type() !== 'page') return;

    const properOrigin = 'https://example.org';
    const pageUrl = target.url();
    if (new URL(pageUrl).origin === properOrigin) return;

    console.log(`Closing page ${pageUrl}...`);
    const newPage = await target.page();
    await newPage.waitForTimeout(3000);
    await newPage.close();
    console.log(`Page ${pageUrl} closed.`);
  });

  const [mainPage] = await browser.pages();
  await mainPage.goto('https://example.org/');
  await mainPage.evaluate(() => {
    window.open('https://google.com');
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

Answer (score 0):

For people just trying to close the current page, when you assign

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

You can then just go:

```js
await page.close();
```

and that will close the current page.